# Exporting inner function from object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

If i have a certain object say:

```
function object1(){

  function func(){...}

 *rest of objec1 content*  

 ...}

 exports.func=func;  //<---this is wrong (compiler error);
```

is there a way for me to export func() from outside object1 bounds?

or,within the object1 bounds, and in this case, how to use it from another place?

Comment: Asking technical questions 101: ***What*** compiler error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've omitted part of your source, but what you have looks fine if I fill in the blanks:

```
function object1(){

  function func(){...}

  exports.func=func; 
}
```

Something needs to call `object1` at some point, e.g.:

```
object1();
```

or

```
new object1();
```

...in order for the `exports.func = func;` line to run, but that's fine provided you do it.

Or did you mean this doesn't work:

```
function object1(){

  function func(){...}

}

exports.func=func;
```

If so, of course not, there's no `func` symbol defined in the scope where you're using it. You'd have to do something like the first code block above.